An inequality for arctan in terms of hyperbolic tangent and radicals
Problem :
Let $x>0$ then define :
$$h\left(x\right)=\arctan\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{7}\left(1-\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\frac{7}{2}}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-31/21\right)\left(1-\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\frac{19}{9}}$$
Show :
$$h(x)>0$$
Some context :
I'm currently finding a series for arctangent in terms of hyperbolic tangent .
A first start should to use derivatives to complete $h(x)$ and speed up a series for the Catalan constant .
What I can show is :
Let $x>0$ :
$$\arctan(x)>\tanh(x)$$
Using a derivative .
Some remarks :
the limits at zero and infinity is zero . Currently I cannot find a shorter expression with this pretty good accuracy .
Question :
How to show $h(x)>0,x>0$ and $x$ a real number ?
Ps: we are in radian .Curiously $31+9=40=21+19$.


Some tought :
Let $0<x<1$ be a real number then we have :
$$f\left(x\right)=x^{\frac{1}{a}},a=0.0652 $$
$$g\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{f\left(\left(\frac{-a^{\frac{1}{2}}+n}{20-a^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}a}\right)20!}{n!\left(20-n\right)!}x^{n}\left(1-x\right)^{20-n}>x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
Now as :
$$3+4=7,4/2=2$$
we just need to add a square term and for the $19/9$ expand .
There is several inequalities for tangent hyperbolic and $\arctan(x)$

Using Bernstein's polynomials we significantly improve the convergence using $h(x)$ instead of using the classical alternating harmonic series .

Some work here : let $0<x<1$ then define $$f\left(x\right)=1-\tanh\left(x\right),p\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{2}\frac{2!}{n!\left(2-n\right)!}f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{\left(2-n\right)}\right)}{1-\tanh\left(1\right)}\right),j\left(x\right)=p\left(x\right)-\left(\frac{\left(1-\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}{1-\tanh\left(1\right)}\right)+\frac{1}{1-x^{\frac{10}{9}}\left(1-x^{\frac{10}{9}}\right)}-1,j(x)\approx \frac{\left(e^{\left(x^{a}\left(1-x\right)^{a}\right)}-1\right)}{e^{\frac{1}{4^{a}}}-1}j\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),a=1.5$$

We have a series even if I don't get the end as we have for $x>M>0$ : $$\left(\frac{80}{x-\frac{3}{4}}-\frac{x}{\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{a_{1}x^{3}}{\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{4}+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{a_{n}x^{2n+1}}{\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\left(2n+2\right)}+\frac{1}{2}}+...\right)\simeq 100\left(\arctan\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{7}\left(f\left(1/x\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}\left(f\left(1/x\right)\right)^{\frac{7}{2}}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{31}{21}\right)\left(f\left(1/x\right)\right)^{4}\right)$$

I give some hint over $x\in (1/2,1)$ so Partial hint :
We have :
$$x^{\frac{3}{2}}-g\left(x\right)<0,g\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{2x^{2}}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x\left(1-x\right)}{x+1}\right)-\frac{1}{4}x\left(1-x\right)-\frac{10}{89}x\left(1-x\right)^{8}$$
Then using Lambert's Continued fraction  for tangent hyperbolic we have :
$$t\left(x\right)=\frac{x\left(x^{6}+126x^{4}+2205x^{2}+10395\right)}{\left(16x^{6}+630x^{4}+5670x^{2}+10395\right)}>\tanh(x)$$
$$h\left(x\right)=\arctan\left(x\right)-t\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{7}g\left(1-t\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{3}g\left(1-t\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\left(1-t\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-31/21\right)\left(1-t\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{\frac{19}{9}}>0$$
We can find other bound for the last radicals in $19/9$ and use the derivative of $\arctan(x)$
Ps: I cannot do simpler.

Hoping that I did not make any mistake, the problem is for $x\in (0,1)$ only.
Expanding as a series $h'(x)$ around $x=1$ to $O((x-1)^n$ and using power series reversion  converting the result to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_{\text{min}}^{(n)} & h\big(x_{\text{min}}^{(n)} \big) \\
 1 & 8.74501\times 10^{-1} & 1.68844\times 10^{-5} \\
 2 & 8.63552\times 10^{-1} & 1.13519\times 10^{-5} \\
 3 & 8.57216\times 10^{-1} & 9.77529\times 10^{-6} \\
 4 & 8.54659\times 10^{-1} & 9.46569\times 10^{-6} \\
 5 & 8.53320\times 10^{-1} & 9.37722\times 10^{-6} \\
 6 & 8.52610\times 10^{-1} & 9.35063\times 10^{-6} \\
 7 & 8.52210\times 10^{-1} & 9.34185\times 10^{-6} \\
 8 & 8.51979\times 10^{-1} & 9.33881\times 10^{-6} \\
 9 & 8.51841\times 10^{-1} & 9.33770\times 10^{-6} \\
 10 & 8.51758\times 10^{-1} & 9.33728\times 10^{-6} \\
 11 & 8.51707\times 10^{-1} & 9.33712\times 10^{-6} \\
 12 & 8.51676\times 10^{-1} & 9.33706\times 10^{-6} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
You could be interested to know that
$$x_{\text{min}} \sim \frac{1+3 \,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{3\left(3+\sqrt{e}\right)}\quad \quad\quad\text{absolute error} =4.25\times 10^{-8}$$

hoooray Claude is come back !

@Ranger-of-trente-deux-glands. We could do the same for the maximum expanding around $x=\frac 12$ and using the same process. and get $x_{\text{max}}=0.528122$

If you want a monster see the following : $$f\left(x\right)=\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x!x!!x!!!x!!!!x!!!!!x!!!!!!x!!!!!!!!x!!!!!!!!!}{1-x!x!!x!!!x!!!!x!!!!!x!!!!!!x!!!!!!!x!!!!!!!!!}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{1+x}}},\left|\left(\frac{1}{e!+\frac{2}{7}+\frac{1}{e}-e}+\frac{\pi}{10}\right)e^{-1}-f\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)\right|<5* 10^{-7}$$
